# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row for the below Query

Tags: sql, oracle

When i execute the following query in sql developer, i'm getting the following error message
"Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
select TPNATIVENAME as PTPNAME,
       INTERFACENAME as CTPNAME,
       DIRECTIONALITY,
       NENAME,
       NCNAME
from TP ,
  (select DIRECTIONALITY
   from SNCCOMPONENT
   where SNCID =
       (select unique SNCID
        from AFFECTEDXCS
        where PXCID = -124)),
  (select NODE.NAME as NENAME,
          NC.NAME as NCNAME
   from NODE NODE,
        NETWORKCONTROLLER NC
   where NODE.HANDLE =
       (select unique SRCNEID
        from SNCCOMPONENT
        where SNCID =
            (select unique SNCID
             from AFFECTEDXCS
             where PXCID = -124))
     and NC.HANDLE = NODE.NCHANDLE)
where NEID =
    (select SRCNEID
     from SNCCOMPONENT
     where SNCID =
         (select unique SNCID
          from AFFECTEDXCS
          where PXCID = -124))
  and TPID =
    (select SRCTP
     from SNCCOMPONENT
     where SNCID =
         (select unique SNCID
          from AFFECTEDXCS
          where PXCID = -124))
union
select TPNATIVENAME as PTPNAME,
       INTERFACENAME as CTPNAME,
       DIRECTIONALITY,
       NENAME,
       NCNAME
from TP,
  (select DIRECTIONALITY
   from SNCCOMPONENT
   where SNCID =
       (select unique SNCID
        from AFFECTEDXCS
        where PXCID = -124)),
  (select NODE.NAME as NENAME,
          NC.NAME as NCNAME
   from NODE NODE,
        NETWORKCONTROLLER NC
   where NODE.HANDLE =
       (select unique SRCNEID
        from SNCCOMPONENT
        where SNCID =
            (select unique SNCID
             from AFFECTEDXCS
             where PXCID = -124))
     and NC.HANDLE = NODE.NCHANDLE)
where NEID =
    (select SINKNEID
     from SNCCOMPONENT
     where SNCID =
         (select unique SNCID
          from AFFECTEDXCS
          where PXCID = -124))
  and TPID =
    (select SINKTP
     from SNCCOMPONENT
     where SNCID =
         (select unique SNCID
          from AFFECTEDXCS
          where PXCID = -124));
```

I'm not getting which inner query is returning multiple values and how to solve this error?

Comment: You'd need to narrow down the problem.  Take each individual subquery on its own and determine whether it ever returns multiple rows.  Unless you're going to give us a reproducible test case, we can't really do much to debug the issue.

Comment: her you can find an sql formatter: http://sqlformat.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UNIQUE X FROM Y
```

This query does not guarantee that your query will return single-row. It may return multiple rows. It only guarantees that it won't return the same X more than once.

So, you need to use `IN` instead of `=`.

For example:

```
SELECT SINKTP FROM SNCCOMPONENT
WHERE SNCID IN (SELECT UNIQUE SNCID FROM AFFECTEDXCS WHERE PXCID = -124)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these SQL gives you only one value:

```
SELECT UNIQUE SNCID
  FROM AFFECTEDXCS
 WHERE PXCID = -124

SELECT SRCNEID
  FROM SNCCOMPONENT
 WHERE SNCID = (
                SELECT UNIQUE SNCID
                  FROM AFFECTEDXCS
                 WHERE PXCID = -124
               )

SELECT UNIQUE SRCNEID
  FROM SNCCOMPONENT
 WHERE SNCID = (
                SELECT UNIQUE SNCID
                  FROM AFFECTEDXCS
                 WHERE PXCID = -124
               )

SELECT SINKNEID
  FROM SNCCOMPONENT
 WHERE SNCID = (
                SELECT UNIQUE SNCID
                  FROM AFFECTEDXCS
                 WHERE PXCID = -124
               )

SELECT SINKTP
  FROM SNCCOMPONENT
 WHERE SNCID = (
                SELECT UNIQUE SNCID
                  FROM AFFECTEDXCS
                 WHERE PXCID = -124
               )
```

And if one (or more) returns you more than one rows, as a quick solution, you can add the the `rownum < 2` predicate to the where clause or replace exact the `=` sign with the `IN` word.